# How to make ASP.NET authentication persist the Url Fragment when redirecting to the login page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, authentication, url

After I inserted the configuration below in my Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="appNameAuth"
   path="/" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="user" password="password" />
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

All requests to

```
Menu.aspx#fragment
```

are redirected to

```
login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Menu.aspx
```

and I expected it to be redirected to

```
login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Menu.aspx#fragment
```

How to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: You would need to encode # (%23). I'm not sure the best option for doing this. Maybe you can fix it with a rewriting rule?

Comment: @Claudio I guess the rewrite is the only option

Comment: Actually (sorry for the confusion) don't think you'll be able to solve it with a rewrite rule. The problem here is that "inline anchors" (#fragment) are managed on client side, this part of the url DOESN'T GO to server. When the server logic detects that you're not authorized to access to "Menu.aspx" it redirects to the login page, losing the inline anchor. I'll let you know if I came up with any solution.

Comment: @Claudio of course it DOES GO to the server. I am trying to prove that to Eoin below too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I have found so far is to use a Rewrite rule to encode the `#` character to  `%23`.

Thanks Claudio!

Comment: Can you give a little more detail about how you did this?

Comment: @MCS I used a String.Replace in the `login.aspx.cs` file

Answer (score 5):

That `#fragment` anchor tag is a client side (browser) component of the URL. It doesn't get sent to the WebServer as far as I know so the server-side has no clue about it as part the redirect.

**EDIT**

Can you check your IIS logs and confirm that because I'm 99% sure that that's not the case.

From a quick test on my local machine.

1. Attempt to browse to

   http://localhost/formstest/private.aspx#test
2. Get Redirected

   http://localhost/formstest/login.aspx?redirect=http%3a%2f%2flocahost%2fformstest%2fprivate.aspx#test

   (Notice the `#` is not escaped as part of the redirect url.
3. Check IIS for first hit.

   2010-04-12 13:36:45 W3SVCxxx 127.0.0.1 GET /formstest/private.aspx 80 - DETAILS SNIPPED - 302 0 0

   (Notice the 302 Redirect and the absense of the `#test` token on the URL
4. Check IIS for the redirect hit.

   2010-04-12 13:36:46 W3SVCxxx 127.0.0.1 GET /formstest/login.aspx redirect=http%3a%2f%2flocahost%2fformstest%2fprivate.aspx 80 - DETAILS SNIPPED - 200 0 0

   (There's your 200 OK HTTP Response and still no `#test`

Like I said, the server doesn't know anything about the #anchor. It's only on the client side regardless of whether you put it in before or after the request is made, or whether you update it with JQuery... it doesn't go to the server.

Comment: I'm sorry, you would be right if this #fragment was changed after the page request, but in my case the #fragment is sent to the server.

Comment: why the down vote? I've added more detail explaining that the anchor is NOT part of the request... ever. have a read of this, or try recreate it yourself and check the IIS logs. http://www.mikeduncan.com/named-anchors-are-not-sent/

Comment: @Eoin You showed me the logs, but the logs are incomplete, but when I am handling the request in the `aspx.cs` file I have access to the hash via `Request.Url.Fragment`. Such property wouldn't exist if such information never reached the server.

Comment: @Eoin and the problem is exactly that step 2 doesn't happen as you describe, the `Fragment` doesn't appears in the redirect parameter

Comment: @Jader - if you read the XML Docs on the `Fragment` Property... it says "Gets the escaped URI Fragment"... in other words if it's not escaped and just a `#` then it won't work... anyway glad you have a solution with your URL rewriting rules...

Comment: @Eoin maybe the escaped doesn't refers to the `#` itself, but to the content after it

Answer (score 3):

I found that using an IIS URL rewrite rule did not work for me.  However the solution provided at the following link worked perfectly:

http://codetunnel.io/how-to-persist-url-hash-fragments-across-a-login-redirect/

Comment: This worked really well!  Especially the last suggestion where you append the window.location.hash onto the form's action attribute.